# Iphone-saving full size image to document directory hangs my app

Tags: iphone, memory-management, document

I am working on an app similar to photo app in iPhone. The flow is I get images through `UIImagePickerController`. When I use Actual image and further save that image to documents,
My app hangs. I saw on profile tool that allocation goes to 19 to 20 mb. If there is any solution to that.

1. Getting image from `UIImagepicker` controller
2. Saving it to documents.

   ```
    -(NSString *)saveImageInDocumentsAtPath:(NSNumber *)number
   {
      NSString *fileName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%@.png",number];
      NSString *imagePath= [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@",    [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0],fileName];
      UIImage *image = self.selectedImage.image;
      NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
      [imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
      return imagePath;
   }
   ```

Comment: why you not compress the ratio of image ?

Answer (score 1):

A typical image is going to be around 3Megabytes, if I am not mistaken (depending on the iPhone and its camera).  So going from 19 to 20 is not unreasonable.  Why you are at 19 to begin with ay be another question.  See if you're loading in too many other images, large files etc.

If you use AV Foundation instead of ImagePicker, you have some other options for handling the images.

And you can write the image to the filesystem asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a great opportunity for some error checking in your code.

Why not try this?

```
-(NSString *)saveImageInDocumentsAtPath:(NSNumber *)number
{
    NSString *fileName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%@.png",number];
    NSArray * docDirectoryArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    if(docDirectoryArray)
    {
        NSString *imagePath= [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@",    [docDirectoryArray objectAtIndex:0],fileName];
        UIImage *image = self.selectedImage.image;
        if(image)
        {
            NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
            if(imageData)
            {
                BOOL success = [imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
                if(success)
                {
                    // only return the image path in the success == YES case
                    return imagePath;
                } else {
                    NSLog( @"did not save file to %@", imagePath);
                }
            } else {
                NSLog( @"could not get image data out of the image");
            }
        } else {
            NSLog( @"no image selected");
        }
    }
    // you might want to check in the caller to make certain the imagePath is NULL
    return NULL;
}
```